# Why the player is falling inside the plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The plane is the ground has a mesh collider.

I found that only if I change for testing the Capsule Collider Height to 5 and the Radius to 5 the player will not fall but will walk too high above the ground.

The way it is now the collider is on the player and touches the ground and yet the player is walking and moving inside the plane.

The ground settings :

[image: Ground settings]

The player settings :

[image: Player settings]

When running the game the player is inside the plane the ground not falling down but inside :

[image: Player inside the planer(ground)]

Comment: Sorry, I can’t see the images, so I am just going to guess. Is the mesh collider’s mesh variable set to ‘plane’? Try attaching a box collider to the plane, and see if it has correct collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you have to turn on "convex" on the "floors" `Mesh Collider` as described in the docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html

Have you tried it adding a `Box Collider` to the plane instead of a `Mesh Collider`? Just for testing it?

Or could it be that another `Mesh` inside the player model has a rigidbody but should not have one?

Comment: Not sure what was the problem but I just imported the player package again and now it's working. Sorry for the mess.